# what does addSbtplugin do

Tags: scala

I have noticed that to add an external library (eg `Scalatest`), I need to follow the following 3 steps

1. Add these lines to your build file: This tells that my code needs this library

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"

2) resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases" - This I suppose tells from where to get the library

Why do I need to do this 3rd step? What does `addSbtPlugin` do?
3. Then adding the following line to project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.3")
```

Comment: i think this can help. https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Plugins.html

Comment: It's just commercial SuperSafe compiler with additional features for ScalaTest. It is optional so only `libraryDependencies` is enough for using the testing library. Actually I haven't seen that kind of ad on ScalaTest Install page before